# what does ClusterMembership class in weka do?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cluster-analysis, weka, categorization

I'm using weka for some classification experiments. i was trying some of the features provided by weka that can be applied on extracted attributes, and I found that applying clustermembership on the attributes will provide relatively higher accuracy than other methods. I'm not quite sure what this feature does since it removes all the attributes and only keeps something like pCluster_0_0 , pCluster_1_0 , pCluster_2_0 and the class-attribute.So I'm not quite sure the results that I'm getting from this is valid and will it work for other new unseen instances. From Weka documentations

> A filter that uses a density-based clusterer to generate cluster membership values; filtered instances are composed of these values plus the class attribute (if set in the input data). If a (nominal) class attribute is set, the clusterer is run separately for each class. The class attribute (if set) and any user-specified attributes are ignored during the clustering operation.

I do appreciate any help to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

It basically does what the documentation you read describes! It uses a clustering algorithm to get the cluster membership of each input instance (i.e. the cluster the instance belongs in) and outputs them as new instances. A word of caution that the clustering algorithm used must be a density based clusterer, so DBSCAN or expectation maximisation for instance.

As for if your result is valid, you will need to run a test set against the clusterer or do percentage split evaluation. You could be overfitting your data!